# AWS Java 2.x TransferManager How to get TransferState in TransferListener?

Tags: aws-java-sdk-2.x, awss3transfermanager

In the *new* AWS Java SDK v2 TransferManager how do I get the equivalent of com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferState in the v1 TransferManager?
I assume it's using a TransferListener and the SdkResponse, but would rather not have to experiment to re-invent the wheel here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may want to implement a [TransferListener](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/transfer/s3/progress/TransferListener.html).

Comment: Yeah, I went with emulating the TransferState enum in a TransferListener that I use instead of the returned objects

Comment: So... I actually went down this route, and the TransferListener is never actually called :/ I had even based my "wait for all complete" on the TransferListener instead of waiting for the Future and none of my implemented methods were ever hit. I switched to just waiting on all of the futures and still, none of my logs from those TransferListener methods were logged. I see at least 3 open bugs about similar issues, maybe one day! :shrug